# Compare distributions using Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD)

Tags: distributions, kernel-trick, two-sample

I use MMD distance to run a permutation test and decide whether two sample distributions come from the same distribution or not. For the MMD, I use a gaussian kernel, the bandwidth of which I select by calculating the median of the pairwise distances between the samples. However, as someone might expect, if the samples differ on a much different scale than their actual values, then the bandwidth might not be sufficient to capture the differences. If I transform the data prior to testing using a common transformation (using for example the minimimum of the minima and the maximum of the maxima to scale each sample in a new range), then it might be possible for the median heuristic to achieve a good result. My question therefore is the following: will such linear transformations enhance always the kernel-based test? In other words, given that the distribution characteristics are affected in the same way (same linear transformations) will their difference become more distinguishable (if they indeed come from different distributions) or will stay the same (if they come from the same distributions and the test has said so in the first place)?

As a note, the test consists of computing MMD statistic on the original data, and then this is compared to the distribution of MMD statistics that results from comparison between random permutations of the (merged) dataset. In this way, a p-value can be extracted.

Comment: I cannot easily address all of the assumptions being made simultaneously, but in general a Gaussian smooth of data is a convolution, and anything other than the identity convolution will produce a distribution that is not the same as a generating (i.e., theoretical distribution from which the data may arise) distribution.

Comment: Maybe in simpler words, what I try to say is that if there are any differences in the original data, will a transformation enhance them so that a given test approach can detect it? And similarly, if no differences occur will the transformation produce robust results? The whole approach seems similar to me as with common machine learning approaches (distance-based) where we first scale the data.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the bootstrap rather than permutation. That may be enough to increase the statistics with lesser variance inflation than data smoothing can offer.

Comment: Look at [Efron-Gong](http://tyigit.bilkent.edu.tr/gradmetr/bootstrap.pdf), it may help.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by smoothing. I only do a linear transformation to the data which is not a convolution

Comment: How is a Gaussian kernel operation not a convolution? If it is not, then I am not understanding what you are doing, please explain.